# How to convert IList<Object> to a JsonArray?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

I have a IList and I wanted to convert it to a JsonArray to return in method JsonResult. How could I do this ?

**Note:** I'm using Json.NET

trying.

```
public JsonResult findByCriterio(String criterio){
            Empresa empresa = getEmpresa();
            IList<CategoriaProduto> lista = new List<CategoriaProduto>();
            if (criterio.Length >= 5){
                lista = dao.findByCriterio(criterio, empresa);
            }else{
                lista = dao.findAll(empresa);
            }
            var jsonArray = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lista, Formatting.Indented);
            return Json(jsonArray);           
        }
```

Entity

```
[Serializable]
public class CategoriaProduto{

    public virtual long id { get; set; }
    public virtual String descricao { get; set; }
    public virtual Empresa empresa { get; set; }

    public CategoriaProduto(){        
    }

    public override string ToString(){
        return descricao;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are double-serializing your result by using both `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` and the `Json()` MVC controller method.  You either need to do this:

```
var jsonArray = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lista, Formatting.Indented);
return Content(jsonArray, "application/json");
```

or this:

```
return Json(lista);
```

If you use the first method, you'll also need to change the return type of your controller method from `JsonResult` to either `ContentResult` or `ActionResult`.

If you use the second method, be aware it does not use the Json.Net serializer internally (it actually uses [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)), so it won't honor any Json.Net settings or attributes that you may be using.